# Show cross-domain image via php

Tags: php, image, cross-domain

I have a script that displays the images via php. `www.maindomain.com/image.php?img=test.jpg` serve images, and i have other sites, where these images are displayed like this 
`<img src="www.maindomain.com/image.php?img=test1.jpg">`

But this script, for show image is on my `www.firstsite.com` and `www.secondsite.com`. Is posibble to log which site is showing image? (put it to database for example).

I know, i can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it's not 100%. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid because of the nature of HTTP the `REFERER` approach is a good as it gets, however there are some smart ways to implement it like this one: http://alistapart.com/article/hotlinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only 100% failsafe way to do it is to share the same image with different URLs. F.i. `www.maindomain.com/image.php?test1.jpg&ref=first` and `www.maindomain.com/image.php?test1.jpg&ref=second`. As actually this images are not requested by first or second servers but by visitor's browsers. Having different GET params in URL makes it easy to log data you need.